# How to compare enum data annotations with string - C# & .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, enums

I'm working on small C# / .NET Core app (REST API) and user is able to post string through Postman which might have following values:

```
"Day Shift", "Night Shift", "Part Time"
```

And I also have enum values defined as:

```
public enum Shifts
{
    [Display(Name = "Day Shift")]
    DayShift = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Night Shift")]
    NightShift = 2,
    [Display(Name = "Part Time Shift")]
    PartTimeShift = 3
}
```

Since I'm receiving values as string, I wrote simple method to ensure that provided value exists in my enums:

```
private bool IsValidEnumValue(string shiftType)
{
    var successfullyParsed = Enum.TryParse(shiftType, out Shifts shifts);
    return successfullyParsed;
}
```

Then I realised that I must take care of a upper/lower letters so I modified method to look like this:

```
private bool IsValidEnumValue(string shiftType)
{ 
    // CODE BELOW THROWS EXCEPTION
    var shiftType = (Shifts)Enum.Parse(typeof(Shifts), shiftType, true);    
}
```

So my question is actually if user passes in "night shift" to recognize if that value is part of my defined enum type.

```
[Display(Name = "Night Shift")]
NightShift = 2,
```

But this obviously ain't working and I'm stuck here.

Any kind of help would be awesome!

Thanks guys.

Cheers

Comment: Seems a little nuts to use `Enum.TryParse()` just to get the boolean return value, just before then separately getting an enum instance.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thanks for suggestions mate, How could I solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How about this (removing the spaces and using the generic method case insensitive):

```
private bool IsValidEnumValue(string shiftType)
{ 
    return Enum.TryParse<Shifts>(shiftType.Replace(" ", ""), true, out Shifts _);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use reflection and extension methods. It is one of the reasons why I don't really like using Data Annotation with Enums. There are better solutions out there, but here is what you need to do.

```
internal static Shifts ToEnum(this Shifts e, string enumDisplayValue)
    {
        Type type = e.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] members = type.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public); // Only return Enum constants
        if (members.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < members.Length; i++)
            {
                if (members[i].GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().Name.Equals(enumDisplayValue))
                    return (Shifts)Enum.ToObject(typeof(Shifts), e);
            }
        }
        return 0; // Invalid value
    }
```

Hope that helps!